# Is XML schema validation of Citrus usable if the schemas have no target namespace?

Tags: xml, spring, citrus-framework

I have tried to set up an `XsdSchemaRepository` in Citrus that contains some XML schemas. Because these schemas have no target namespace (they are not mine, I cannot fix this), I also configured a `RootQNameSchemaMappingStrategy` because the default strategy to map namespaces does obviously not work.

However, I failed because of the following Exception in a Spring class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class path resource [path to my schema file] has no targetNamespace
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:181)
    at org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.loadSchema(SimpleXsdSchema.java:128)
    at org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleXsdSchema.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
```

Is it possible to do XML schema validation with Citrus if the schemas have no target namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target namespace restriction comes from Spring's SimpleXsdSchema implementation. You could implement your own subclass that provides a default namespace though:

```
public class NoTargetNamespaceXsdSchema extends SimpleXsdSchema {

    @Override
    public String getTargetNamespace() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(super.getTargetNamespace())
                       .orElse("urn:uuid:" + UUID.randomUUID());
    }
}
```

You can add the custom implementation to the Citrus schema repository as Spring bean reference:

```
<bean id="noTargetNamespaceXsdSchema" class="com.consol.citrus.xml.schema.NoTargetNamespaceXsdSchema">
  <property name="xsd" value="path/to/sample.xsd"/>
</bean>

<citrus:schema-repository id="schemaRepository">
  <citrus:schemas>
    <citrus:reference schema="noTargetNamespaceXsdSchema"/>
  </citrus:schemas>
</citrus:schema-repository>
```

Comment: Works perfect, except that `super.getTargetNamespace()` does not return `null` but an empty String. Thanks